# Given set of Linearly Independent vectors, prove that Linear Transformation of that set is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation and $V$ is finite dimensional. Suppose $Im(T) = V$. Prove that if $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{T(v_1),\dots,T(v_k)\}$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the rank-nullity theorem $\dim V = \dim ker T + \dim im T$, so $ker T = \{0\}$. Then, consider
$$
a_1T(v_1) +\cdots + a_kT(v_k) =0 = T(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k).
$$
so $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k\in kerT$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Yes, so since ker{T} = {0} then it follows that $a_1=a_2=...=a_k=0$

Comment: exactly! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I see. I didn't make the connection from dim{ker{T}}=0 to ker{T} = {0}.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k a_iT(v_i)=0 \to \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k T(a_iv_i) = 0 \to T\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i\right)=0$. Since $Im(T) = V \to dim(Im(T)) = dim(V) \to dim(Ker(T)) = 0 \to Ker(T) = \{0\} \to \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i=0 \to a_i = 0,\forall i =1,...,n \to T(v_1),T(v_2),\cdots T(v_k)$ are linearly independent.